# MVC 3 razor validation after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I have a form, that is rendered with customer information. There is a drop-down that, when changed, inserts new form elements in the HTML with JavaScript. I got the JavaScript for validating after this event.

When I post the form, I do get the array of new elements into my model. If now I do server validation and there is an error, I return everything back to the view, generating this time the new elements using razor. All good so far. However client side validation is not working!
I do get validation for other elements in the form but not for the ones generated from the collection, that was added manually previously.

I do see that the data-val attributes are not there for the array of elements.

If the view is rendered all together, including the looping for the array of values, why I don't get client validation on this section of the form?

```
@{if (Model.pasajeros != null)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < Model.pasajeros.Count(); i++)
          { 
            <p>Pasajero: @(i + 1)</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="lblspan">Nombre</span></td><td><span class="lblspan">Primer Apellido</span></td><td><span class="lblspan">Segundo Apellido</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].name, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })<br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].name)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].lname, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })<br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].lname)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].lname2, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })<br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].lname2)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="lblspan">Fecha de Nacimiento (mm/dd/yyyy)</span></td><td style="vertical-align: bottom"><span class="lblspan">Sexo</span></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].dob, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })<br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].dob)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].sex, Model.sexoItems, new { @class = "ddlsmall" })</td><td></td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        <p>@Html.RadioButtonListFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].radioselect, Model.radioItems) </p>

        <table>
            <tr>
            @if (Model.pasajeros[i].radioselect == "pass")
            {
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom"><span class="lblspan" id="@("numeroA" + i.ToString())">Número de Pasaporte Americano</span><span id="@("numeroR" + i.ToString())" class="statehide">Número de Residencia</span></td>
            }
            else
            {
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom"><span class="statehide" id="@("numeroA" + i.ToString())">Número de Pasaporte Americano</span><span id="@("numeroR" + i.ToString())" class="lblspan">Número de Residencia</span></td>
            }
            <td style="vertical-align: bottom"><span class="lblspan">Fecha de Vencimiento</span></td>
            <td><span class="lblspan">Número de Pasaporte Cubano</span></td><td  style="vertical-align: bottom"><span class="lblspan">Fecha de Vencimiento</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @if (Model.pasajeros[i].radioselect == "pass")
                {


                <td>@this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].numAmericanPassport).Id("numAmericanPassport" + i).Class("txtboxsmall")

                @this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].numResidencia).Id("numResidencia" + i).Class("statehide").Disabled(true)
                <br /> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].numAmericanPassport) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].numResidencia)</td>
                <td>
                @this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].expAmericanPassport).Id("expAmericanPassport" + i).Class("txtboxsmall")

                @this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].expResidencia).Id("expResidencia" + i).Class("statehide").Disabled(true)
                <br /> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].expAmericanPassport) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].expResidencia)</td>
                }
                else
                {
                <td>@this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].numAmericanPassport).Id("numAmericanPassport" + i).Class("statehide").Disabled(true)

                @this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].numResidencia).Id("numResidencia" + i).Class("txtboxsmall")
                <br /> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].numAmericanPassport) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].numResidencia)</td>
                <td>
                @this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].expAmericanPassport).Id("expAmericanPassport" + i).Class("statehide").Disabled(true)

                @this.TextBox(x => x.pasajeros[i].expResidencia).Id("expResidencia" + i).Class("txtboxsmall")
                <br /> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].expAmericanPassport) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].expResidencia)</td>
                }
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].numCubanPassport, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].expCubanPassport, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="lblspan">Habilitación</span></td><td><span class="lblspan">Documento</span></td><td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.pasajeros[i].visa, new { @class = "txtboxsmall" })</td>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="file" name="documents[@i]" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
      }
  }
```

}

That is part of my view

Comment: You will have to show some code. Especially the bit which executes the not-working part of validation (bot client ans server side parts). But post only the relevant bits, not the whole file.

Comment: This is a pretty common issue with jquery's validation of dynamic elements.

Comment: I have found out that is happening only with FluentHTML controls..? Does anybody knows the reason why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `parse` method after you have added new elements to the DOM in order to register them with the unobtrusive validation:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#id_of_the_form_containing_newly_added_inputs');
```

Obviously those elements must have the corresponding HTML5 `data-*` attributes that indicate the validation rules that you want to apply on them, the same way the inputs added on the server do.